# Kafka log level adjust with yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm running Kafka in a Kubernetes environment. 
I want to adjust kafka log level to `WARN`.  I have a yaml file which I used with `helm install`.
In that yaml, there is a `envOverrides` parameter. Can I just add the following? And then `kubectl apply`?

Before:

```
envOverrides: {}
```

After:

```
# Do I need { } ? 
envOverrides:
  kafka.log4j.root.loglevel: WARN
  kafka.log4j.loggers: "kafka.controller=WARN,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=WARN,state.change.logger=WARN"
```

Comment: It's not clear what image you're using, but by default logger levels aren't set by environment variables in Kafka

Comment: have you already tried passing parameters via `envOverrides`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using `confluentinc/cp-kafka` image.  Maybe adding `logLevel: WARN` `rootLogLevel: WARN` `kafkaLogLevel: WARN` these values to yaml might work?

Comment: @Nick No not yet.

Comment: @JinLee , which exactly kafka chart did you install and is it possible for you to provide me with the yaml file you have been using with `helm install`? I'd like to reproduce the case locally

Comment: @Nick https://hub.helm.sh/charts/incubator/kafka

Comment: @Nick I will also put yaml file (temporarily)

Comment: @Nick I would really appreciate if you can help. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables are `KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL` and `KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS`

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/operations/logging.html

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to use helm chart. Is there a way to set that in `values.yaml`?

Comment: so maybe I go `KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL : WARN` in `values.yaml`?

Comment: I don't know how helm works, but wherever `envOverrides` or just the variables for the kafka images are